# PHP chord transposer

Tags: php, regex, string

Im working on a script that needs to find a match for certain letters(chords) in the text and then replace them.

1. But there are certain exceptions. If the next "2"spaces are empty
   they are match.
2. If there is only one empty space, but the second space also
   contains a letter that is match with the above rules aswell.

EX (Match these A,Am,B,C#) : And the text is :

Am B 
A plane came down C# B

In this example the (Am, the B, C# and B) should get match but not the "A" plane.

Im not really good with string functions and regex any help would be greatly appreciated

Im basically trying to write a transposer, but my major concern is that its going to select the wrong text thanks

Comment: it sounds impossibru? How would you differentiate between the chords `Am B` with lyrics `"A plane came down"` (as your current example), and another (fictional) song with chords `Am B A` with lyrics `"plane came down"` ?

Comment: could you maybe use some sort of `code` for the chords?  Like wrap them all in parens? ex: (Am) (B) A plane came down (C#) (B).  Or alternatively, wrap the lyrics in quotes?

Comment: Standard music chord notation dictates that you put chords *above* the lyrics of the song, on their own line. With PHP, this becomes very easy to parse with a bit of Regex validation (to check if the line is a "chord" line or a "lyric" line). From there, you can easily explode the string into pieces and transpose accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have no control over the input (e.g. you're scraping these from tablature websites), and for some reason these chords are interleaved between words instead of resting between lines, then here's a start:

```
<?php

    $mods = '(?:maj|m|min|sus|add9|aug|dim|dom|...)';
    $regex = "/\b([ABCDEFG][#b]?$mods?)\s+/"

?>
```

I'm afraid, however, I don't understand your "next 2 spaces" constraint.  If you're trying to distinguish between the chord, "A", and the word, "A", though, I advise against your method.  Instead, consider the following alternate rule, though far from perfect.  "A" is the only chord that is commonly a word by itself, so *if* your lyrics are well-capitalized, a hint that "A" is a word and not a chord is that the next word is an uncapitalized word:

```
    Am B A plane came down C# --> Am B C#

    Am B A Plane came down C# --> Am B A C#
```

If you think about it, aside from context clues, this is how humans can tell, too.  To make a regex out of this strategy, one would consider the lone "A" a special case, as follows.

```
<?php

    $mods = '(?:maj|m|min|sus|add9|aug|dim|dom|...)';
    $regex_1 = '((?:A(?!\s)|[BCDEFG])[#b]?$mods?)';
    $regex_2 = '(A(?=\s+[a-z]))';
    $regex = "/\b(?:$regex_1|$regex_2)\s+/";

?>
```

See a running demo here: http://rubular.com/r/tRjozL7KCx.

This is far from perfect but something you can start with and improve.

UPDATE: An explanation, to help learn.

```
\b                      A word-boundary, so "A plane came down and CRASHED
                        into the sea" will not match "D" as a note.
(?:                     A non-capture group.  (Ignore this for now.)
    (                   A capture group.  (To encapsulate $regex_1.)
        (?:             A non-capture group.  (Ignore this for now.)
            A(?!\s)     An "A" not followed by whitespace, i.e. a "lone A".
            |           An "OR" operator.
            [BCDEFG]    Any one of these characters, B C D E F G.
        )
        [#b]            Any one of the characters, # b.
        ?               Says the previous entity (# or b) is optional.
        $mods           Any one of the modifiers, e.g. maj m min ...
        ?               Says the previous entity (maj m min ...) is optional.
    )

    |                   An "OR" operator.

    (                   A capture group.  (To encapsulate $regex_2.)
        A(?=\s+[a-z])   An "A" that is followed by at least one whitespace
                        character, then a lower-case letter.
    )
)
\s+                     A bunch of whitespace.
```

Comment: o wow thanks, this is really helpful im still trying to understand all those regex expressions, im stuck how would I add support for / chords such as G/C, G#/C#

Comment: @AndreEscudero - I updated the answer with an explanation.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After several hours of reading and trying out stuff here is my regex
`([ABCDEFG][b#]?(?=\s(?![a-zH-Z])|(?=(2|5|6|7|9|11|13|6\/9|7\-5|7\-9|7\#5|7\#9|7\+5|7\+9|7b5|7b9|7sus2|7sus4|add2|add4|add9|aug|dim|dim7|m\|maj7|m6|m7|m7b5|m9|m11|m13|maj7|maj9|maj11|maj13|mb5|m|sus|sus2|sus4|\))(?=(\s|\/)))|(?=(\/|\())))`

[link](http://rubular.com/r/tCvNexsmq3)
While the example on that website sometimes misses the slash chords(E/G# etc..) On PHP it includes them.

It is quite long but it does the job of handling all possible weirdness that can happen.Any way to improve it?

Comment: Oh and this just select the root chord no minor,maj,sus, etc so then I can just convert them to an int and either subtract or add to transpose correctly.

Comment: @AndreEscudero - Wow, this is really good!  I admit I haven't tried to understand the ending but for the rest it looks like you've made some great improvements, e.g. [a-zH-Z].  Off hand I see nothing I could improve. I'm curious to try whatever tool you're making so post back here if you finish, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

OK anyways here is the class that transposes chords still needs some tweaks but for now it suits my needs.

[PHP CHORD TRANSPOSER CLASS](http://pastebin.com/994jy3ab)

It detects almost any possible chord and picks up inline chords aswell.
If you include Flats chords it will tranpose to flats not sharps, same goes for sharp, 
Default is sharp so  F Transpose by 1 is F# not Gb

It also supports PDF creation just download [DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/downloads/list) and uncomment the include and lines 82-86 and remove the echo from the $html variable.

Hopes this helps, but it is still far from perfect lol but it hasnt miss any chords so far

Test it out with multiple songs and post feedback errors etc

Comment: I didn't see this until today.  Nice work!